# Hyperledger Fabric network - Channels and ledgers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Fabric network,

there can be more than one channels. Who maintains the ledger in the private channel?
What is the link between records in the private channel and the public enteries? Is it the unique ID of the record?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one channels in the fabric network. A channel can be joined by multiple organizations and it provides a way for private communication among them (for example, these organizations would like to transact with each others and keep the data private to the network). When you create a channel, you implicitly create a ledger that is scoped to that channel only. This ledger will then record all the transactions in this channel. Every peer within the organization in a channel maintains a copy of the ledger. Whenever there is a transaction, this will be recorded to the ledger of **EACH** of the peer in that channel.

Not sure what do you mean by public entries but that basically how it works. Hope it helps!

You can refer to the following links for more information.

1. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/ledger/ledger.html
2. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/glossary.html#channel

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid if i got the point. Ok for example, in a sea food scenario. There are many nodes involved. If two nodes do the data transaction in a private network. The data is stored in the private ledger of the private channel. What aabout other nodes in the network who are not a part of this channel. Will they know that some data has been transacted between two nodes and not know the in depth confidential details? If yes, then how it is linked with public ledger in the network.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid if i got the point. Ok for example, in a sea food scenario. There are many nodes involved. If two nodes do the data transaction in a private network. The data is stored in the private ledger of the private channel. What aabout other nodes in the network who are not a part of this channel. Will they know that some data has been transacted between two nodes and not know the in depth confidential details? If yes, then how it is linked with public ledger in the network.

Comment: @Gulshan In Fabric, every ledger in a channel is tied to a channel. I believe there is no global/public ledger that is visible to the whole network unless you create one channel and every organizations within the network join that channel. As the intention of a channel is to provide data privacy and transaction isolation in the network, peers that are not part of a channel will not be able to read/write to the ledger of that channel.